# Missing the grtt10 font on MikTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

Getting an error when running Latex. Here is an abbreviated output around where I believe the error is:

```
Font metrics written on grtt10.tfm.
Output written on grtt10.600gf (252 characters, 51904 bytes).
Transcript written on grtt10.log.
METAFONT failed for some reason

Sorry, but maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Nikolaj/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

! Font \tengrtt=grtt10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.36 \def
         \greekmode{%
? s
```

Not quite sure how to read it. In my installation line 36 of [slgreek.sty](http://tug.ctan.org/fonts/greek/levy/slgreek.sty) says

> \def\greekmode{%

Is this the problematic line or is it line 35?

> \font\tengrtt=grtt10

If it's the font, what font am I missing and how do I install it? The Miktex options app doesn't seem to list it:

[image]

[Ctan.org](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/greek/levy) says grtt10.mf is a "Parameter file for 10pt Typewriter". Not a font file.

This is the (hopefully) relevant bit of TEX:

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{hebtex}
% NB next line must *follow* \usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{slgreek}
%\input greekmacros
```

Contents of miktex-maketfm.log (not much there):

```
2020-07-25 00:06:05,042+0300 INFO  miktex-maketfm - starting with command line: miktex-maketfm -v grtt10
2020-07-25 00:06:05,099+0300 INFO  maketfm - Making grtt10.tfm from "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\grtt10.mf"...
2020-07-25 00:06:05,199+0300 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2020-07-25 00:06:05,200+0300 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-mf.exe --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; nonstopmode; "input grtt10"
2020-07-25 00:06:13,576+0300 INFO  maketfm - METAFONT failed for some reason
```

Unabbreviated output follows in case there's more clues:

```
Command Line:   latex.exe --src --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "DissTree.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\Nikolaj\Documents\NSEXTERNAL_PC_FINAL\DISSERTATION

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(DissTree.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\book.cls"
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\bk12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\longtable.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cyrillic\ot2enc.def")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\cyrillic\ot2cmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\endnotes\endnotes.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\switch.def")
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabi\bblopts.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-english\english.ldf"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\switch.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\babel-russian\russianb.ldf"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\lscape.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvips.def")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\footmisc\footmisc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\rotating.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\arabtex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\aconfig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\arabaux.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\acmd.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\afonts.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\afonts2.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\ascan.sty"
(ArabTeX) scanner for code `arabtex' installed.
(ArabTeX) input encoding set to ArabTeX standard conventions.)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\aparse.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\awrite.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\xarbsymb.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\arabskel.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\xarbskel.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\aboxes.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\arabtoks.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\arabchrs.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\aligs.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\aoutput.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\abidir.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\atrans.sty"
(ArabTeX) ZDMG transliteration.)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\alatex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\afoot.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\abjad.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\apatch.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\alists.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\asect.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\atabg.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\alocal.sty"
(ArabTeX) 3.11 local stub, 26.02.2006))
Arabic processor `ArabTeX' [20060702 patch level 3.11s (02.07.2006)]
(ArabTeX) ... now be patient ... )
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hebtex.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hecmd.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hescan.sty"
(ArabTeX) scanner for ISO 8859-8, CP1255, and other Hebrew codes installed.)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\heparse.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hewrite.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hebsymb.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hebchrs.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hetrans.sty"
(ArabTeX) ArabTeX default transliteration)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hefonts.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hefonts2.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\hepatch.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\levy-font\slgreek.sty"Making grtt10.tfm from "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\grtt10.mf"...
Running miktex-mf.exe...
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\grtt10.mf
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\cm\cmbase.mf)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\grbase.mf)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\greek.mf
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\upper.mf [65]
[66] [69] [72] [73] [75] [77] [78] [79] [82] [84] [81] [90] [71] [68] [74]
[76] [88] [80] [83] [85] [70] [89] [87])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\graccent.mf
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\gen_acc.mf) [96]
[39] [126] [34] [60] [62] [86] [67] [64] [94] [95] [92] [35] [36] [32] [124]
[30] [31]) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\lower.mf
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\a.mf
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\gen_sigma.mf)
[97] [128] [129] [130] [131] [132] [133] [134] [135] [136] [137] [138] [139]
[140] [141] [142] [143] [144] [145] [146] [147] [148] [149] [150] [151]
[248] [1]) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\b.mf
[98] [2]) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\g.mf
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(1)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.70457
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(2)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.7374
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(3)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.77023
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(4)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.80305
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(5)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.83588
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(6)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.8687
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(7)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.90152
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(8)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.93436
! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.
<to be read again> 
                   superness
<for(9)> ...r,S[]l,temp[];pair.p;interim.superness
                                                  :=((EXPR0)/10)[sup,1];mess...

drawloop->...ersectiontimes.curv2r;endgroup;endfor
                                                  ;if.S1l=-1:S1l:=2;fi.if.S2...

gen_letter->...{up}...z2e{right};drawloop(2,3,4,5)
                                                  ;filldraw.z5l{right}...z5'...

this_letter->...ture:=savedpicture;else:gen_letter
                                                  ;fi.if.not.working_hard:pi...
l.53 this_letter
                ; penlabels(1,2,3,3',4,4',5); endchar;
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.96718 [103] [7])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\d.mf [100] [4])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\e.mf
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.7364 [101] [224] [225] [226] [227] [232] [233] [234] [235] [5])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\z.mf [122] [26])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\h.mf [104] [152]
[153] [154] [155] [156] [157] [158] [159] [160] [161] [162] [163] [164]
[165] [166] [167] [168] [169] [170] [171] [172] [173] [174] [175] [249]
[8]) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\j.mf [106]
[10]) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\i.mf [105]
[200] [201] [202] [203] [208] [209] [210] [211] [216] [217] [218] [219]
[240] [241] [242] [243] [9])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\k.mf [107] [11])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\l.mf [108] [12])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\m.mf [109] [13])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\n.mf [110] [14])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\x.mf [120] [24])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\o.mf [111] [228]
[229] [230] [231] [236] [237] [238] [239] [15])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\p.mf [112] [16])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\r.mf [114] [251]
[252] [18]) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\s.mf
[115] (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\gen_sigma.mf)
[99] [19] [253] [254] [255])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\t.mf [116] [20])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\u.mf [117] [204]
[205] [206] [207] [212] [213] [214] [215] [220] [221] [222] [223] [244]
[245] [246] [247] [21])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\f.mf [102] [6])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\q.mf [113] [17])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\y.mf [121] [25])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\w.mf
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.7364
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.76569
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.79498
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.82426
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.85356
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.88284
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.91212
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.94142
change in superness required; increased to 
>> 0.9707 [119] [176] [177] [178] [179] [180] [181] [182] [183] [184] [185]
[186] [187] [188] [189] [190] [191] [192] [193] [194] [195] [196] [197]
[198] [199] [250] [23]))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\digits.mf [48]
! bad pos.
<to be read again> 
                   ;
pos->...XPR3)<=currentbreadth:errmessage"bad pos";
                                                  fi.fi(x(SUFFIX2)r-x(SUFFIX...
l.50 pos1(light_stem,0)
                       ; pos2(light_stem,0);
! bad pos.
<to be read again> 
                   ;
pos->...XPR3)<=currentbreadth:errmessage"bad pos";
                                                  fi.fi(x(SUFFIX2)r-x(SUFFIX...
l.50 pos1(light_stem,0); pos2(light_stem,0)
                                           ;
[49] [50] [51] [52] [53] [54] [55] [56] [57])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\grpunct.mf [123]
[125] [33] [37] [29] [3] [40] [41] [42] [43] [44] [46] [47] [58] [59] [63]
[61] [91] [93] [28] [45] [0] [127])
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\levy-font\lig.mf) ) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Font metrics written on grtt10.tfm.
Output written on grtt10.600gf (252 characters, 51904 bytes).
Transcript written on grtt10.log.
METAFONT failed for some reason

Sorry, but maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Nikolaj/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

! Font \tengrtt=grtt10 not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.36 \def
         \greekmode{%
? s
OK, entering \scrollmode...
) (DissTree.aux (Rumi-Yunani.aux) (Transliteracii.aux))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\apatch.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\alocal.sty"
(ArabTeX) 3.11 local stub, 26.02.2006)
(ArabTeX) version 3.11s (02.07.2006): second phase of patching)
(Transliteracii.tex ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\arabtex\uxnsh.fd")
Overfull \hbox (21.7353pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--34
[]\OT2/cmr/m/n/12 Orfografiya zapisannykh arabskimi bukvami grecheskikh slova, 
opredelennykh

[... more "overfull" messages omitted ...]

Package footmisc Warning: Some footnote number(s) were out of range 
(footmisc)                see log for details.

(DissTree.aux (Rumi-Yunani.aux) (Transliteracii.aux) (IzuchenieYazyka.aux)
(SlovaPrizraki.aux) (Bibliogr.aux) (Bahlultable.aux)
No file CommBahlulTable.aux.
(iwn.aux) (HunainGrechYazyk.aux) (Trial2.aux) (Landscape.aux))

 *File List*
    book.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
longtable.sty    2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
 fontenc.sty
  ot2enc.def    2001/08/11 v3.3a Cyrillic encoding definition file
  ot2cmr.fd    2001/08/11 v3.2c Computer Modern Cyrillic font definitions
endnotes.sty    
   babel.sty    2017/11/03 3.15 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of b
abel
 english.ldf    2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
russianb.ldf
  lscape.sty    2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   dvips.def    2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
rotating.sty    2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 arabtex.sty    2003/08/22  3.11 ArabTeX main module
 arabaux.sty    2003/05/21  3.11 auxiliary macros for ArabTeX
    acmd.sty    2003/08/20  3.11 Arabic command processing 
  afonts.sty    1995/11/16  3.04 define Naskh font 
 afonts2.sty    1998/10/19  3.10 define Naskh fonts for LaTeX2e
   ascan.sty    2003/08/22  3.11 standard ZDMG input encoding 
  aparse.sty    2003/05/26  3.11 get syllables 
  awrite.sty    2003/06/05  3.11 build output word 
xarbsymb.sty    1998/07/15  3.07 symbolic output encoding 
arabskel.sty    2000/06/04  3.10 character skeleton definitions 
xarbskel.sty    1999/07/17  3.09 character skeleton definitions 
  aboxes.sty    2003/05/28  3.11 build output boxes
arabtoks.sty    1999/07/17  3.09 ArabTeX CS token definitions 
arabchrs.sty    1998/07/11  3.07 letter token definitions 
   aligs.sty    2003/05/26  3.11 compute ligatures
 aoutput.sty    2000/06/04  3.10 build output lines
  abidir.sty    2003/08/22  3.11 bidirectional linebreaking
  atrans.sty    2003/06/14  3.11 generate the transliteration 
  alatex.sty    2003/05/04  3.11 ArabTeX extensions for LaTeX 
   afoot.sty    2003/05/12  3.11 ArabTeX footnotes
   abjad.sty    2003/04/26  3.11 abjad numerals 
  apatch.sty    2006/07/02  3.11s last minute patches 
  alists.sty    2003/04/26  3.11 inverted list macros
   asect.sty    2003/04/26  3.11 section macros for Arabic
   atabg.sty    1997/01/21  3.05 LaTeX tabbing macros for Arabic
  hebtex.sty    2000/06/12  3.10 modifications for Hebrew mode
   hecmd.sty    2007/07/26  3.12 additional commands for Hebrew
  hescan.sty    2002/03/07  3.10a scanner for HED and ISO 8859-8 encoding
 heparse.sty    2003/04/27  3.11 Hebrew parser routines
 hewrite.sty    2003/05/21  3.11 for all supported Hebrew fonts
 hebsymb.sty    2000/06/12  3.10 for oldcode font assignments
 hebchrs.sty    2003/04/26  3.11 Hebrew letter token definitions 
 hetrans.sty    1999/07/17  3.09 Hebrew transcription module
 hefonts.sty    1997/07/02  3.06 standard Hebrew fonts
hefonts2.sty    2003/04/27  3.11 define Hebrew fonts for NFSS2
 hepatch.sty    2001/09/17  3.10- patches for Hebrew
 slgreek.sty    
  apatch.sty    2006/07/02  3.11s last minute patches 
Transliteracii.tex
   uxnsh.fd     1999/10/19 v3.10 ArabTeX Naskh extd. font definitions
    uheb.fd     2000/06/13 v3.10 ArabTeX Hebrew font definitions
  omscmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
DissTree.ent
 ***********


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on DissTree.dvi (13 pages, 74992 bytes).
SyncTeX written on DissTree.synctex.
Transcript written on DissTree.log.


_____________________________________________________________________

 LaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 13)

 Errors: 1   Warnings: 3   Bad Boxes: 72
_____________________________________________________________________
```

OS: Windows 10.

Thank you for having a look. I'm completely new to this so any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your TeX distribution would appear to be at least 3 years old. (E.g., you report `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>`, whereas the latest version of the LaTeX kernel is `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`. You report `Babel <3.15>`, whereas the current version is `<3.47>`. You report `Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h`, whereas the current version is `book 2019/12/20 v1.4l`.) Any chance you could run the MikTeX Package Manager program and thoroughly update your entire TeX distribution, including all packages?

Comment: in a current miktex the creation of the tfm of the fonts fail too, it doesn't like something in the mf sources. Do you have to use these packages? arabtex, hebtex and slgreek are from the last century and certainly not what I would suggest to a new latex user to write this languages.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes, I'm afraid we will have to deal with these last-century packages as the tex is already written. I'm just helping someone fix this problem. Apparently it used to work before. @UlrikeFischer

Comment: find or install a texlive, at least the one font could be created there (you could then copy the tfm over to miktex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are suggesting a fix while I am still unsure about the root cause of the problem. All I have is "METAFONT failed for some reason". I'd like to understand the reason before attempting a fix.

Comment: @Mico I am a bit wary about updating the whole thing. Who know what else I might break? This person whom I'm helping has been using this installation for a while and it used to work fine for them.

Comment: metafont takes the sources (the mf-files) and creates from them a needed file (the missing tfm). This is quite standard for such bitmap fonts and normally it happens automatically (you can see that miktex is starting this maketfm). But there are errors in the metafont run and while a tfm is created somewhere miktex doesn't copy it to the right place.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Suppose I copied the tfm to "the right place". Would that stop METAFONT from failing? Where is the "right place" for grtt10.tfm? (Or is it tengrtt.tfm?)

Comment: well if the tfm is there it wouldn't try to create it, but it could then fail later when trying to make the pk-files. Sorry but this old, unmaintained fonts are a problem. If you can try to compile on overleaf - then you know if a texlive system can handle it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why are old fonts a problem? Fonts are just data in a certain format, right? Has the format changed since those fonts were created? The obvious problem here is ridiculously poor error reporting ("METAFONT failed for some reason") which prevents me from diagnosing and fixing the issue.

Comment: The "some reason" problem is as old as 1997: "Miktex's metafont didn't give me any info to go on" https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/eRra-lBj7nA

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you know where MikTex is expecting to find the tfm? " Metric (TFM) file not found."

Comment: You get very good error messages: They start in your log above after `! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.`. And no, metafont fonts are not a simple data format. They are like your tex file a source (mf) which has to be compiled to get the usable tfm/pk font. And like your tex file can contains error and not compile, it can happen that metafont compilation fails. I have no idea if the font was always faulty, but as it is old and nobody uses them anymore there is not much hope that they get fixed.

Comment: Oh. So the message ```! The token `superness' isn't an internal quantity.``` is the underlying error that ultimately makes METAFONT fail? What does it mean though? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Perhaps I need an *older* MikTex to match the age of grtt10? It has to have worked at some point.

Comment: No it doesn't need have to worked without error at any time. People could have simply ignored the error. Installing an old miktex is difficult. Imho your best chance is to try texlive  instead of miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What dictates the use of grtt10? Is it the slgreek package? Is there a way to tell slgreek to use a different Greek font?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your advice to use TexLive. Why do you think it should solve the problem with grtt10? Does TexLive not use maketfm? Can installing TexLive break anything in MikTex? E.g. because they use shared components?

Comment: I tried the one font with texlive, and while it gave an error with metafont it recovered enough to let pdflatex compile. I'm *not* saying that will solve your problem, I'm only saying that is your best chance. it will not interfere with miktex, I have both on my PC. You only need to change the PATH variable to switch between the systems.

Comment: The MikTeX package you want for `slgreek` and `grtt10.mf` is [`levy-font`](https://ctan.org/pkg/levy-font).  There is also a version a few years newer, but still from last century: `lgreek`.  A modern document would probably use `babel`.